# Symfony2 - $query-getResult() returning a blank page in prod environment

Tags: symfony, bundles

I recently reinstalled my vendors

```
    php app/bin vendors install --reinstall
```

Since then in my prod environment I get a blank page (not an error) after any

```
    echo "1";

    $array = $query->getResult();

    echo "2";
```

it outputs a blank page with :

```
    1
```

**But everything is working fine in the dev environment**... I indeed tried to clear my cache but still get the blank page in the prod environment.

I tried to var_dump( $query ) which appears in both environment, the only difference seems to be

```
    // prod
    private '_proxyDir' => string 'C:\wamp\www\AppName\app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies' (length=55)

    // dev
    private '_proxyDir' => string 'C:\wamp\www\AppName\app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies' (length=54)
```

Here is my deps file :

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.9

[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.5.1

[monolog]
    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
    version=1.0.2

[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.5

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.5

[swiftmailer]
    git=http://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
    version=v4.1.5

[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.2

[twig-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions.git

[metadata]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git

[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x

[SensioDistributionBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[SensioGeneratorBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=v1.0.1

[FOSUserBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/UserBundle

[FOSFacebookBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle.git
    target=/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[FacebookSDK]
    git=git://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.git
    target=/facebook

[FOSCommentBundle]
    git=https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/CommentBundle

[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
    target=bundles/FOS/RestBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSerializerBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle.git
    target=bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle
```

Any idea, How to debug that ?

Comment: I just deleted prod.log, refresh my blank page and nothing is happening in app/logs...

Comment: Then change in your app.php (or another production index file) the line `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` to `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` and see if something happens. This will enable displaying errors, so make sure you disable it after you fixed your production.

Comment: @meze I set it to true, refresh my page, then set it back to false and I don't have this blank page anymore... kinda weird. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to warmup prod cache and regenerate proxies with this command:

```
./app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```